# React App not re-renderedring

Tags: reactjs

This is how my render function looks like

```
render() {
    const { Ether } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <Container text>
          <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <Label>Ether Value</Label>
            <Input
              name="Ether"
              value={Ether}
              onChange={this.handeleChange}
              placeholder="Enter Ether"
            />
            <Button type="Submit">ADD PLAYER TO LOTTERY</Button>
          </Form>
          <Button onClick={this.pickWinner}>PickWinner</Button>
        </Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

And this is my handleChange

```
  handeleChange = (e, { name, value }) => {
    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  };
```

- From what understand about react ,the component is re-rendered ,every
  time I set the state .So shouldn't my onChange handler ,be causing
  multiple renders as i keep typing in the input box.
- Here is my componentdidMount

  ```
  async componentDidMount() {
     const Manager = await lottery.methods.manager().call();
     const Players = await lottery.methods.getPlayers().call();
     const Balance = await web3.eth.getBalance(lottery.options.address);
     this.setState({
       Manager,
       Balance,
       Players
     });
   }
  ```

  How i want it to work is ,everytime I hit submit ,I want the componentdidmount to be called ,i.e the component to be re-rendered ,but this is not whats happening.

What am I missing here ? is there more to component rendering that I havent grasped yet ?

Comment: How is the `Input` component defined? Are you sure it's passing the `name` and `value` parameters to your `handleChange` as you expect?

Comment: If you make an example [here](https://stackblitz.com/fork/react) I'll take a look for you.

Comment: So do you want state to be updated when you type or when you click submit? It's not clear.

Comment: @Colin Please stop spamming that under every question tagged `reactjs`.

Comment: @trixn It's not spam, I only post it when I could easily fix their code if I could run it. If I can fix it by reading it, I don't ask for an example.

Comment: Hi The answers below helped ,Being new to react ,I was not able to grasp the difference between a component mounting and a component updating ,In my case ill put the statements in componetdidUpdate instead of mount and try it out .

Answer (score 1):

```
- componentDidMount is a life cycle method of react. componentDidMount
- will call only once after render. When you change state, render
- function will call again but componentDidMount will not.
```

## checkout link for your reference

[React life cycle method componentDidMount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)

```
 componentDidMount() {
     yourfunction();
 }

 handeleChange = (e, { name, value }) => {
    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
    yourfunction();
 };

 yourfunction () {
    const Manager = await lottery.methods.manager().call();
    const Players = await lottery.methods.getPlayers().call();
    const Balance = await web3.eth.getBalance(lottery.options.address);
    this.setState({
        Manager,
        Balance,
        Players
    });
 }
```

Comment: This works for me, but in my case I have multiple functions like handleChange ,so calling yourfunction everytime ,looks a bit of a repetitive task,as stated in one of the answers ,would using componetDidUpdate be a better solution ?

Comment: @TanmayBhattacharya:- componentDidUpdate will call after second time render call. That is not a safe place to call `your function` in your case. As you said you have multiple function like handleChange. Let say you have a function call  handleChange, handleChange1. In case of handleChange and handleChange1, you need to update state and call yourfunction, yourfunction1 respectively. In that case componentDidUpdate will call and both `yourfunction, yourfunction1` will call as you want to call only one function at a time.

Comment: @TanmayBhattacharya To know about more about react life cycle react below links.

[https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html ] (React Life cycle)

[https://gist.github.com/hdlion/0a6fad76878fcabcf2e6bf20170f713a`] (React Life cycle)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `componentDidMount()` is called after the component mounts.

Secondly, your input does not appear to be set up correctly. For a simple example of how to handle input, see [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-5ucuc5).

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React'
    };
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    const name = e.target.value;

    this.setState({
      name,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Hello name={this.state.name} />
        <input onChange={this.handleChange} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: No, `componentDidMount()` only is called during initialization, unless the component is unmounted, otherwise `componentDidUpdate()` is called.

Comment: Sorry, I meant after the component mounts.